# Issue when accessing the text of an element

Tags: jquery

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>wddsa</td>
    <td>dffs</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('tbody tr').each(function() {
    name2 = $(this).children("td:first").text;
    alert(name2);
});
```

Returns a bunch function and jquery code. Possibly from jquery.min. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing the actual function, rather than executing it. (`.text` is a function, not a variable, so you need to execute it to get its return value `.text()`).

```
name2 = $(this).children("td:first").text();
```